# How to do in operation in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    f = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = ForeignKey(ModelA)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to get f in model A and I know b . How can I do this by using django orm ?

Comment: The question isn't totally clear. Is it that you want to find all `ModelB` instances with a specific value for their `b` field, and then find the related `ModelA` instances? If so, this is simple enough - what have you tried? (And please clarify if I've misunderstood.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these queries:

```
a_models = ModelA.objects.filter(model_b__b=known_b_value)
for a in a_models:
    print(a.f)

b_models = ModelB.objects.filter(b=known_b_value).select_related('a')
for b in b_models:
    print(b.a.f)
```

`select_related` in the second query is not strictly necessary; it is only used to get the `f` values in the first query rather than in one additional query per loop item.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
ModelA.objects.filter(b=value_matching_b).values('a__f').all()
```